# Load F# assembly in Powershell and create a record expression

Tags: powershell, f#

I have a `Powershell` script. I successfully loaded a `C#` assembly and used a method contained in one the classes in that assembly: `[MyCSharpAssembly.MyClass]::MyAssemblyMethod()`. However the same did not work for `F#`.

Is it at all possible?

I have an assembly called `Data.dll` and it has a module called `People.fs` and `People.fs` defines record types:

```
module People =  
    type Teacher = {
        FirstName:string,
        LastName:string,
        Age:int }
```

I want to load the `Data.dll` assembly to my `Powershell` script and then create a record expression of type Teacher inside the script to use it in some other calculation in that script.

How do I do that if it can be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An F# record compiles to a read-only class, so you should be able to create a value using `New-Object`, passing in the values as constructor arguments.

```
New-Object Teacher("Jane", "Doe", 27)
```

You may have to pass the fully-qualified name instead of `Teacher`.

Comment: Worth noting: when passing the fully qualified name use the `+` sign: `Data+Teacher("Jane", "Doe", 27)` and not `.`: `Data.Teacher...`