# Powershell casting to F# discriminated union

Tags: powershell, f#

I have a `Powershell` script and I have loaded an `F#` library and created an `F#` record expression:

```
$teacher = Data+Teacher("Joan", "Doe", 27)
```

Now I need to pass `$teacher` to a function, but before I do I need to upcast it to type `SchoolEmployee`. When I tried:

```
$schoolEmployee = $teacher -as [Data+SchoolEmployee]
```

I got an empty object back. In my F# module I have a discriminated union:

```
 module Data = 
     type SchoolEmployee =
     | Teacher of Teacher
     | Cleaner of Cleaner
```

How do I upcast to an `F#` discriminated union type in `Powershell`?

Comment: Not sure if this is even supported, but the reason `[Data+SchoolEmployee]` doesn't work is that the `+` inside type strings means "nested class" in PowerShell. Have you tried `[Data.SchoolEmployee]`?

Comment: This question seems strangely related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32973438/126014

Comment: Yes it is, good spot Mark, part of the same project :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using this definition of the `Teacher` record from [the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32973438/126014):

```
module People =  
    type Teacher = {
        FirstName:string
        LastName:string
        Age:int }
```

You can create a new `Teacher` object in PowerShell like this:

```
$teacher = New-Object Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q32987498.People+Teacher("Jane", "Doe", 27)
```

(I hope you will excuse my verbose use of namespace, but that's how I compiled the `Teacher` type.)

This `$teacher` object is an instance of the `Teacher` *record type*:

```
PS> $teacher.GetType().FullName
Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q32987498.People+Teacher
```

The `Teacher` record type isn't the same as the `Teacher` *case constructor*. A case constructor isn't a type; it's a function. This is the reason the cast doesn't work. `People+Teacher` isn't an instance of `SchoolEmployee`. In fact, `People+Teacher` is compiled as a sealed class.

In order to turn it into a `SchoolEmployee` value, you'll need to pass it to the `NewTeacher` method:

```
$emp = [Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q32987498.Data+SchoolEmployee]::NewTeacher($teacher)
```

This `$emp` object is of the type `SchoolEmployee`:

```
PS> $emp.GetType().FullName
Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q32987498.Data+SchoolEmployee+Teacher
```

The `New-Object` statement in PowerShell is equivalent to writing this in F#:

```
let teacher = { FirstName = "Jane"; LastName = "Doe"; Age = 27 };
```

The `NewTeacher` method call is equivalent to this F# expression:

```
let emp = Teacher teacher
```

Here, perhaps it's more evident that the `Teacher` case constructor is a function, which is also the reason it's compiled to a method in IL.